# Is there a way to sort a time series in chronological order using Seaborn Countplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn to create some nice graphs.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.countplot(x="day_name_complete", data=df_fuze)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.countplot(x="day_start", data=df_fuze)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The graphs looks great, but what I really want to do is sort in chronological ascending order.  I tried the following code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.countplot(x="day_complete", data=df_fuze, order=pd.to_datetime(df_fuze['day_complete']).sort_values().index)
plt.show()
```

That gives me an error saying:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-02 00:00:00
```

There should be some way to sort the time series, right.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it a bit more, I figured out two solutions.  There are probably a few different ways to solve this.

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=cats, ordered=True)
df_fuze['day_name_start'] = df_fuze['day_name_start'].astype(cat_type)

f=plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
pass_count = df_fuze['day_name_complete'].value_counts()
sns.barplot(pass_count.index, pass_count.values, alpha=.7)
plt.xlabel('Weekday', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=14)
plt.show
```

[image]

```
df_fuze.sort_values(by=['day_start'], inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
sns.countplot(x="day_start", data=df_fuze)
plt.xlabel('Start Day of Month', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]